# Config settings for workspace and wls

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have several extensions with configuration, but you can only set them at the user level. My extensions' config cannot be set at workspace level or for wls. Can anyone tell me why? What do I need to do to allow users to set settings for wls for example?

The GUI for settings does not show my extension for wls or workspace and if I edit the settings.json in my workspace the options become greyed out and a tooltip explains that they can only be set for the user.

Comment: have you looked at the `scope` property of the configuration item, `"scope": "resource"`. What is `WLS`?

Comment: I tried that, it did not work in wls (Windows Linux Subsystem)